# Global variable alternative in a AWS Step Function execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Im running a workflow using a step function (with SAM), when I needed to send information between lambdas I've used events and everything was perfect! But now, I need that almost every lambda in my workflow have access to a constant received in the invocation input of the step function (it changes on every execution) like a global variable.

I know that I can solve it by returning it in every lambda output but I think that it is a very ugly solution :(

Is there any way to access the context of the execution and add data to it from a lambda in the step function ? Any other solution would be cool too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html#input-output-resultpath-append

You can keep the input of the state machine execution and combine it with the result of the state.

Answer (score 1):

Going through the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html), I see that you can access the `context` object from each state in the state machine.

You can pass the information that you need to be *global* as the input to your state machine and then, access the state machine input from the `context` object.

You can refer the linked doc to see how to access the `context` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your step function invocation input **from any state** by accessing the context object in your state input parameters.

Select the `AWS SDK` integration type for your stage and forward the `$$.Execution.Input` context field to e.g. your lambda payload

[image: pass state]

[image]

[image]

The event for the lambda is

```json
{
  "stepFunctionArguments":{
    "MyKey": "MyValue"
  },
  "payloadFromPreviousState": {
    "task1output": "foobar_result"
  }
}
```